# how to pass data from one function to another in component.ts , angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, variables, components

hi am passing some values on button click "data.someid" i want to get this "data.someid" in another button click

```
html
---
<button (click)="click1(data.someid)"></button>
<button (click)="click2()"></button>
```

component.ts

```
click1(data){
   this.value = data
}
click2(){
  console.log(this.value)
}
```

Now am storing retrieved data into `this.value` on "click1" , and i want to access it in the another button click , but `console.log(this.value)` showing `undefined`

please someone tell me how to access it.

Comment: are you sure this.value = data assignment in function click1() is proper? Try logging the value in click1() function first.

Comment: According to yor code function 2 is dependent on function 1 as this.value variable will be assign data when function1 is clicked.. So in this case if you directly try for function 2 the value will be off course undefined

Comment: Can you add `type="button"` to your button elements and try again please?

Comment: @mayur i want to get this value in click2 , how can i do that.

Comment: @echonax .. Its awesome working fine.. how its working on type="button". and any other ways to use this in "span" click

Comment: @pradeepks I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `type="button"` to your button elements,

```
<button type="button (click)="click1(data.someid)"></button>
```

otherwise the buttons inside the forms will be by default `type=submit` like you were submitting a form. That is why `this` refers to something else inside your `click` scope.

Comment: thanks it working cool.. if am using span instead of button its not working , any other fixes for that???

Comment: @pradeepks It seems to be working fine with spans. Can you reproduce it in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gzD677GPvX3gM1bABNzg?p=preview

Comment: Hi, i checked its working fine with span ... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the variable as local variable inside class? And make sure that you clicked first button before second one.

```
export class SomeClass {
  value: any;

  click1(data){
    this.value = data
  }
  click2(){
    console.log(this.value)
  }
}
```